# How can I refresh the macOS dictionary?

Tags: macos, big-sur, dictionary, spelling

Consider the following workflow:

1. Open TextEdit.
2. Type a word that's not in the dictionary.
3. Right-click on that word and select 'Learn Spelling'.
4. Observe the squiggly underline disappears, as the word is now recognised.
5. Observe the word is added to the `~/Spelling/LocalDictionary` file.
6. Quit TextEdit.
7. Remove the word from the `~/Spelling/LocalDictionary` file.
8. Reopen TextEdit.
9. Type the same word again.
10. Observe it is *still* recognised (not squiggly-underlined), despite no longer being in the local dictionary.

It seems the problem here is that there is some sort of cache maintained by macOS that is not refreshed. If I right-click on the word in TextEdit to remove it from the local dictionary instead of editing the file, it is indeed no longer recognised; i.e., this appears to update the cache.

Is there any way I can manually refresh the cache of local dictionary words?

Comment: Is there a reason that using the provided method is not satisfactory? E.g. are you trying to automate changes to the dictionary, or something else?

Comment: @benwiggy Mainly that it's a great deal easier to edit the text file. And yes, potentially automation in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out myself in the end. One needs to relaunch the `com.apple.applespell` service (from the command line).

```sh
launchctl stop com.apple.applespell
launchctl start com.apple.applespell
```